# $.getJSON url redirects to 404 when data has a string with "/" in it

Tags: jquery, getjson, encodeuricomponent

I have a jQuery.getJSON call with the url string

```
'/addRecipientToMessage/id/' + message_id + '/recipient_name/' + recipient_name
```

I have a problem when the recipient name contains a "/" in it. I tried to encode the url with encodeURIComponent, but it redirects me to 404 page not found.

How could I bypass this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try using `encodeURIComponent` function only on `recipient_name`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` function only on `recipient_name`:

```
'/addRecipientToMessage/id/' + message_id + '/recipient_name/' + encodeURIComponent(recipient_name)
```

Or you can try with `escape()` but it is deprecated after Javascript 1.5

```
'/addRecipientToMessage/id/' + message_id + '/recipient_name/' + escape(recipient_name)
```

Comment: Still gives me a 404 :(

Comment: Did you try with "escape"? 
i.e. ...' + escape(recipient_name)